# Combining GANs and NLP for AI-Based Programming: Generating Input-Output Templates for Computer Functions

Tags: tensorflow, python, chatgpt, encoder-decoder

I would like to combine `GANs` and `NLP` to create a system that can take an input and generate an appropriate output. For example, given the input `9 to the power of 2`, the system would output `pow(9,2)`.

I am not entirely sure how to research this, but I can provide some examples of what I am trying to accomplish.

Example:

Input: `2 * 5`

Output: `mul(2,5)`

Input: `(5*3) + 9 / 7`

Output: `sum(mul(5,3),div(9,7))`

My ultimate goal is to combine AI with programming to give artificial intelligence the ability to use many computer functions. For example, it could retrieve the current date with `Date.now()` or use `ParalelAICapture.getSubject()` to identify what is currently in front of it.

Actually, code suggestion algorithms are giving me somewhat similar results to what I am looking for, but they are a bit blurry for my goal. Therefore, I will use input and output templates for more precise results.

Can someone please explain how to achieve this and provide some examples?